# dynamics 365 crm managed solution not overriding Javascript webresource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have modified a javascript file (myfile.js) in my development environment. After I export it as a patch managed solution and import into my target CRM environment, the changes made to that file is not reflected.

There has been no update to that file directly in the target environment (which we know of). 
The file was originally imported together with other components in a previous managed solution.
The update was created as a patch off the original solution (The publishers are the same).

After importing the log file shows that it was imported successfully. I have republished as few times to be sure it applied the change.

Any advise on what might be causing this will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You are not alone.. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/261346

Comment: This isnt very helpful, but I gave up with managed solutions years ago. They just cause problems. If an unmanaged solution would work for you as as well I would suggest switching over.

Comment: Did you try overwriting customizations while updating a solution (by import)?

Comment: Yes, but did not work. For the moment, I have imported it as unmanaged as it was a single file to get around the problem. But would be good to discover the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have attribute **solutionaction** in Library tag.

Example:

```
 <formLibraries>
     <Library name="your_resource_file" libraryUniqueId="{GUID}" solutionaction="Added" />
 </formLibraries>
```

Allowed values are:

```
<xs:simpleType name="solutionactionType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Added" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Removed" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Modified" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType >
```